# setHandler into views_pre_render OR count results in views_pre_render

Tags: views, 8

I have a view that needs to have a custom views footer only if it get results. Otherwise the view needs to not be displayed

I can set up a view footer by using `$view->setHandler` with `hook_views_pre_render` and I can count results with `hook_views_pre_render`

How can I achieve both with a single function? Using `$view->setHandler` with hook_views_pre_render does not attach the footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an alternative solution, by using `hook_views_pre_render` and `$view->attachment_after`

```
$view->attachment_after = array('#markup' => '<a href="/" title="Title" class="button">Button</a>');
```